# Adding watermark to excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have an application that reads data from a sheet in excel file prints the out in another sheet in the same file.

For my own satisfaction I want to add a watermark to that sheet where the output is displayed.
I am working with C# and .NET

Do I need to paste any specific code? I am not sure what would you need. Please ask if you require more details

Library used for handling excel objects -:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

//creating an object of Application
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

//creating an object of Workbook
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0,false,
                            5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                            "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

//creating an object of Sheet
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = (Excel.Sheets)excelWorkbook.Sheets;
```

Comment: You should specify what library do you use to read and write sheets in Excel workbook.

Comment: Excel doesn't really support watermarks. It does however support adding a big fat image to the header that will go behind your sheet data, and does indeed *look* like a watermark. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Paul-Jan can u specify how can that be done, If that suffices the purpose well and good.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel supports opening HTML, you can generate Html tables that are opened using excel. This piece of html code adds a Background Image or Watermark (not html standard though) to your excel generated file. You need to have the image file at the same folder as the HTML file that is opened in excel. This is for the case where you don't use any .NET Framework for generating Excel compatible files.

**Generated_Excel.html:**

```
<html>
<body background="1.png">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td> 
            <td>Column2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value Column 1</td> 
            <td>Value Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Final Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Syncfusion XlsIO  then [this code](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/kb/1954/How%20do%20I%20insert%20watermark%20in%20MS%20Excel) is the one you have to use:

```
// Set the image as sheet background
sheet.PageSetup.BackgoundImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this issue and since I didn't find a solution anywhere I'm posting my working code. This solution works by creating temp image and inserting it on slides. Steps to create code are based on this: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/put-watermarks-photos-word-45076.html link.

```
    public void AddWaterMarkToPowerPoint(string filePath)
    {
        string waterMarkText = "Top secret";

        PowerPoint.Application powerPointApp = new PowerPoint.Application();

        PowerPoint.Presentations pres = powerPointApp.Presentations;

        string imagePath = null;

        try
        {
            PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pres.Open(filePath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            PowerPoint.PageSetup pageSetup = pptPresentation.PageSetup;

            float pageWidth = pageSetup.SlideWidth;
            float pageHeight = pageSetup.SlideHeight;

            CreateTempWaterMarkImage(waterMarkText, ref imagePath, (int)pageHeight, (int)pageWidth);

            for (int i = 1; i <= pptPresentation.Slides.Count; i++)
            {
                PowerPoint.Slide slide = pptPresentation.Slides[i];

                PowerPoint.Shapes shapes = slide.Shapes;

                PowerPoint.Shape shape = shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);

                shape.Fill.UserPicture(imagePath);

                shape.Fill.Transparency = 0.7f;

                shape.Line.Transparency = 1;

                shape.ZOrder(MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringToFront);
            }

            pptPresentation.SaveAs(filePath);

            pptPresentation.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            powerPointApp.Quit();

            //remove temp image
            if (imagePath != null)
                File.Delete(imagePath);
        }
    }

private void CreateTempWaterMarkImage(string waterMarkText, ref string imagePath, int pageHeight, int pageWidth)
{

    float angleRotation = (float)((Math.Atan2((double)pageHeight, (double)pageWidth) * 180) / Math.PI);

    float fontSize = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pageHeight, 2) + Math.Pow(pageWidth, 2)) / 50;

    using (Bitmap newie = new Bitmap(pageWidth, pageHeight))
    {
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newie))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            gr.TranslateTransform((float)pageWidth / 2f, (float)pageHeight / 2f);

            gr.RotateTransform(-angleRotation);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular);

            SizeF textSize = gr.MeasureString(companyName, font);

            gr.DrawString(waterMarkText, font, SystemBrushes.GrayText, -textSize.Width, -textSize.Height);
        }

        string fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            imagePath = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\" + fileName + ".png";

            newie.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```