# c# System.Windows.Control Image to a .bmp file?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to make watermark in Excel, For that I have create a System.Drawing.Image   and converted it to System.Windows.Control Image in c# 
My problem is , after code the image.source, image is null.
My code:

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
        imgWtrmrk.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
       System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new 
       System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        BitmapImage ix = new BitmapImage();
        ix.BeginInit();
        ix.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        ix.StreamSource = ms;
        ix.EndInit();
        image.Source = ix;
```

I have tried a lot of things but  couldn't solve the problem.
  the source is not null but I couldnt assign it the image,

Please help..

Comment: why is this tagged as "excel"? what is imgWtrmrk? please tag your question with type of application (WPF, winforms, etc)

Comment: You need to add ms.Position = 0 so BitmapImage can start reading again from the start of the stream.

Comment: I edit the code :                                                                  
                     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
                    ms.Position = 0;                                                                                                but the result is same

Comment: You have to move the Position back to 0 *after* the Save() call.

Comment: It didn't affect the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heyho, maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
///<summary>
    /// Converts an System.Drawing.Image to an BitmapImage
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="image">System.Drawing.Image</param>
    ///<param name="disposeImage">Image dispose</param>
    ///<param name="format">ImageFormat</param>
    ///<returns>BitmapImage or null</returns>
    public static BitmapImage ImageToBitmapImage(Image image, bool disposeImage = true, ImageFormat format = null)
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            if (format == null)
            {
                format = ImageFormat.Tiff;
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                bmi.BeginInit();
                image.Save(ms, format);
                bmi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                bmi.EndInit();
                bmi.Freeze();
                if (disposeImage)
                {
                    image.Dispose();
                }
                return bmi;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is a method to save the `MemoryStream` to an file. (Untested but it should work)

```
///<summary>
    /// Save an System.Drawing.Image to an file
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="image">System.Drawing.Image</param>
    ///<param name="filePath">Physical path (C:\someimg.bmp)</param>
    ///<param name="disposeImage">Image dispose</param>
    ///<param name="format">ImageFormat</param>
    ///<returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool ImageToFile(Image image, string filePath, bool disposeImage = true, ImageFormat format = null)
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            if (format == null)
            {
                format = ImageFormat.Tiff;
            }
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                image.Save(fs, format);
            }
            if (disposeImage)
            {
                image.Dispose();
            }
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The implementation could look like (XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="Multi_Explorer.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding BitmapImg}"/>

        <!-- or -->

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Height="50" Content="{Binding Img}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BitmapImg = ImageToBitmapImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\some.img"));

        Img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image()
        {
            Source = BitmapImg
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public System.Windows.Controls.Image Img
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public BitmapImage BitmapImg
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Regards,

k1ll3r8e

Comment: Thanks,  in this case how to save it to computer as image file

Comment: I assign the bmi to System.Windows.Controls.Image image.source.Then image is null

Comment: @muratturna Hmm that's a bit strange... Because i use this method in some of my projects and all images shown correctly. Maybe the `Image` it self is `null`? - And about how to save it to an file, if u have an `System.Drawing.Image` u can use `Image.Save(string filename)`.

Comment: ISystem.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image(); // image.Source=ImageToBitmapImage(imgWtrmrk, true, null); then? where do I mistake? your method works there is no problem, image.source is not null but image is null

Comment: @muratturna, what do you mean by "image is null"? If `Image.Source` is not `null` then the image can't be `null`. - It sounds like u have an problem to display the `Image` correctly? - If so, check how u implement the `Image`. In XAML for example, u need a `ContentPresenter` because `Image` can't be the `Image.Source`. But you linked no implementation, so i can only ask my "magic glass ball" what happens. ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am newbie and unfourtanetely that is advance level for me

Comment: The method "CreateTempWaterMarkImage" by Mateusz Migała at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656471/adding-watermark-to-excel-file    is helpfull. My project is working :)

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Control Image to a System.Drawing.Bitmap

```
public System.Drawing.Bitmap TakePhoto()
{
    var bmpImage = (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)base.Source;
    var bmpFrame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bmpImage);

    var bmpEncoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
    bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(bmpFrame);

    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    bmpEncoder.Save(ms);

    return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
}
```